# CLIMAEMET - Interpolation to estimate climate data at municipal level

Tags: interpolation

I have been learning to use the fantastic R package CLIMAEMET generated by @mpizarrotig and maintained by @dieghernan.

I cannot, however, find a way to find an interpolation method to estimate climate variables on each municipality in Spain. For example, how can I obtain an estimated average temperature for all municipalities in Spain?  I would appreciate any help on this question.

Thank you!
Rubén Ruiz-Rufino

Did all tutorials provided in R package but could not find a way to retrieve the desired data.

Comment: what interpolation? linear? polynomial? logarithmic? all of  these can be set up based on the maths.

Comment: Dear Mike, thank you very much for your question. The method proposed by the CLIMAEMET developers is based on IDW method. But what we are trying to find is a way where we can estimate temperatures for each municipality in Spain as weather stations are not necessarily located in those administrative units.

Comment: Perhaps estimate as some weighted average of the two or three nearest. Did that to predict   temperatures for planning heating - results were pretty good.